# Sending a message programmatically to iPad Messages app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to send messages programmatically to the iPad Messages app, but not sure how to do it. I know I can use MFMessageComposeViewController for SMSs but how can I use it (or something else?) for sending messages via Messages (for iPad and iPod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that MFMessageComposeViewController works on the iPad if you have Messages.app on the iPad setup correctly.

Use canSendText method of the MFMessageComposeViewController to determine if the device will allow for sending Text (either SMS or Messages)